# How to get the date part from a date with timestamp column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the date in `DDMMYYY` format from a field that stores date in `YYYY-MM-DD Timestamp` format. (For example, '2018-11-09' should display '09Nov2018').

I know that one way is to use the `datepart` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which can extract the year, month and day individually and then I can concat them.

Edit:  I don't want to use `getdate()`. There is a column which has `YYYY-MM-DD Timestamp` format and from that column I am extracting `'DDMM2018'`. I am using:

```
concat
(
  CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd,columndate)), 
  CONVERT(varchar, LEFT(DATENAME(month, DATEPART(month,columndate)),3)) , 
  CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, columndate))
) AS trial
```

This gives me `'9Nov2018'` and not `'09Nov2018'`. I am planning to convert this back to `datetype' again as that is how I want the result.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Any ideas/suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: If the data type is `date`, then it doesn't store it in any format, that is just how SSMS chooses to show it to you.

Comment: In general, you can use either the CONVERT() function with a suitable formatting code, and massage the result to your linking (chop off the beginning, end, replace unwanted characters with nothing etc). Or use FORMAT() with which you can specify a "pattern" for the returned string. Format uses more CPU, though.

Comment: How are you using `CONCAT()` in SQL Server 2008? Also, [please read this about your `convert()` calls](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: I don't know how it is working but I tried and it worked.

Comment: Then you're not using SQL Server 2008 (which is how you tagged your question), since [`CONCAT()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example using `GETDATE()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(char(11), GETDATE(), 13),' ','');
```

Yields `12Nov2018`. Three days ago, it would yield `09Nov2018`.

To run this against your table:

```
SELECT Trial = REPLACE(CONVERT(char(11), YOUR_COLUMN_NAME_HERE, 13),' ','')
  FROM dbo.YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE;
```

In SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use `FORMAT()` but, like Tibor suggested, this uses more CPU (roughly doubling runtime [in my tests](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time)).

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'ddMMMyyyy');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can't use this as my reference date is not getdate(). There is a column which has YYYY-MM-DD Timestamp format and from that column I am extracting 'DDMM2018'. I am using concat(CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(dd,columndate)),
 CONVERT(varchar, LEFT(DATENAME(month, DATEPART(month,columndate)),3)) , 
 CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(year, columndate))) AS trial. This gives me '9Nov2018' and not '09Nov2018'. I am planning to convert this back to datetype again as that is how I want the result.

Comment: @T.H. you replace `GETDATE()` in my statement with the column name in your query. Your question didn't tell us either the name of the column or the name of the table, so I showed a sample that worked against a function instead.

Comment: Apologies about that, I will update the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Replace(Convert(nvarchar(100),YourDate,106),' ','') gives the desired result
[image]